# How to give a custom (id || key) for every item in flutter listview?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to give custom id to every item in flutter's listview?

I need to update a single item in flutter listview by its id or key.

Why I want to update by Id?

because I want to update a specific item without rebuilding the entire listview items, this may boost performance of my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return Card(
    child: ListTile(
    title: Text(list[index]),
    onTap: () { //                                  <-- onTap
      setState(() {
        list.insert(index, 'updated value');
      });
    },
    onLongPress: () { //                            <-- onLongPress
      setState(() {
        list.removeAt(index);
      });
    },
   ),
  );
 },
);
```

here as you can see you can easily update and delete.

Comment: Thank you this helped me but still a little help, how to update and delete from database too?

Answer (score 10):

I guess you can just use `itemBuilder`'s index since it's not repetitive.

```
return ListView.builder(
         itemCount: items.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
           return ListTile(key: new Key(index.toString()));...
      },
    );
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but I need a custom key of myself because I want to list them using the id came from database, and by Id I can update and delete item from database